# How to improve efficiency of GridView or DetailsView in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview, detailview

In ASP.net when we perform paging over Gridview or DetailsView than the Gridview fetch all rows from the Database each time.

Suppose our Database contains 100 rows and we have configured Paging in Gridview with page size of 10 records per page.But whenever we click on the the pager control of gridview for any particular page no. then GridView should fetch only particular 10 rows from database.

If we click on page no 3 then it should query only rows 21-30 but it fetches all rows and neglect the remaining .which is simply a wastage of resources.

Can any one of please suggest me a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To implement this optimized data fetch, you have to implement custom paging (rather than using the GridView paging). Also, you should use SQL to get only the rows that you want to show on a page (not all of the data).

See the following related links:

[Custom Paging in Asp.net](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rizwan328/DataListCustomPaging01112009021450AM/DataListCustomPaging.aspx)

[Paging tons of data in GridView](http://weblogs.asp.net/lduveau/archive/2007/01/10/paging-tons-of-data-in-gridview.aspx)

[How to get Specific rows From Table by Id Range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035153/how-to-make-an-sql-query-if-want-some-specific-rows-from-specific-place)

[Paging Large Datasets in SQL Server](http://allinthehead.com/retro/260/paging-large-datasets-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 3):

You can using [custom paging in ASP.NET 2.0 datasets.](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020140032/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/031506-1.aspx)

Also, checkout other ways of [paging large datasets](http://allinthehead.com/retro/260/paging-large-datasets-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Sql Server 2005+, you could try using the ROW_NUMBER Function to page the database as explained in this article:

[Paging Records Using SQL Server 2005 Database - ROW_NUMBER Function](http://www.davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2005/12/30/2652.aspx)